# setting a NSDocumentDirectory url for recording?

Tags: objective-c

I am setting my url for recording with :

```
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:[globals sharedGlobals].folderCounter];
NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound1.caf"];

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
```

when `[globals sharedGlobals].folderCounter` is 0 at the start, and it works.
the next time i record i do it in another index:

```
[globals sharedGlobals].folderCounter=[globals sharedGlobals].folderCounter+1;
```

so in the next time i am  trying to record i get error:

```
index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
```

but why cant i create a new place for recording ?i want to have 4 folder 1-2-3-4 and record each time in another one.

how would i do that ?

thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array returned has only one entry at index 0. I think what you want is get the documents directory path and append a filename - then save to $docdir/filenameN.caf. Your should index the filenames like file1.caf file2.caf.

The index in your example can stay at 0. You may also consider creating a subfolder for the car files 1st.